# Vim snipMate LaTeX template

Tags: vim, latex, snipmate

I am using Vim to write my LaTeX files, and figured I'd make a few snippets to help me along. It's been no problem writing simple snippets (like one for `begin`, one for `figure` etc.), but then when I tried making one to set the title (with a default value including some curly brackets (`{`and `}`), I have this problem. The goal of my snippet is that it creates the following text:

```
\title{My name\\\texttt{me@email.com}}
```

I want all the text inside the outmost curly brackets (the ones belonging to `title`) to be a placeholder. I try to accomplish this by writing the snippet as follows:

```
\title{${1:My name\\\texttt{me@email.com}}}${2}
```

My problem, however, is that snipMate seems to use only the name and the email (omitting the    closing bracket for the `texttt` command) as a placeholder.

Comment: I was going to edit your question to make the backquotes appear, but I'm not sure if that's what your snipped should create. Please edit it accordingly, and include a detailed example of what you want to create.

Comment: Sorry, I misclicked the post button. I am updating the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SnipMate has some known problems with these things, the parsing for nested
braces just doesn't work. Maybe someone knows how to do this, but in the
meantime I suggest you creating two snippets, one for `\title` and another for
`\texttt` — just to simplify things a bit.

```
snippet \ti
        \title{${1:My name}}

snippet \te
        \texttt{${1:me@email.com}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess I'll have to go with that, and just hope that snipMate will work this out in the future. :-)